# Migrating to kvm

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, kvm-virtualization

Ours is a small setup. Currently we have two windows/hyper-v servers running around 8 ubutu server virtual machines. The virtual machines were built long time back to the extent that ubuntu version is no longer supported. We are planning to move all virtual machines to Ubuntu 12.04 as its supported long term.

I am trying to decide whether to use kvm or hyperv for new servers and looking for help.

Ideally I would like to build one master machine and clone it and then install machine specific stuff on it. Doing this in hyperv seems to be painful (might be because of my lack of knowledge).

I played with kvm and liked it. I did build one small 20gb file system image as master in kvm and successfully managed to build another machine by "basing" on it. I am thinking of using this approach and sharing host file system using 9p. This way I don't have to worry about figuring out the disk space requirements for each machine etc.

Also based on what I read, moving kvm machines to another host seems to be very simple.

Looking for pros/cons of using this approach - master file based VMS and sharing host file system. Data on any of the machine is not sensitive and machines are not exposed to outside world. The machines are mostly used for qa setup and access to host and vms is controlled by active directory permissions.

Answer (score 0):

master file approach is good, but you need to make sure you plan your space out right - if you simply clone VMs from the master image, that's one thing, but if you take qcow2 snapshots, then those VMs will be thin provisioned and will grow with time. They will also not be able to be moved directly to another host, you'll also need to take the base image, or flatten the existing one first.

Another thing to watch out for - make sure you prepare the base image with `oem-config` before you start cloning/snapshotting it.